# Could quantum vacuum polarization increase GR frame dragging beyond the predicted values and therefore replace DM explanation of galactic rotation?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, dark-matter, modified-gravity, frame-dragging

[image: frame dragging effect]
image source credits:[David Butler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqopDx2F6Lk)

This anomalous speed rotation distribution of galaxies is today mainly contributed to Dark Matter.

However, since a definitive experimental measurement and verification by [experimental tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging#Experimental_tests) of the predicted values of [frame dragging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging) by the [Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging#Mathematical_derivation) does not exist yet, especially for galaxies, how can Dark Matter specialists be sure that this is not a candidate for explaining the anomalous rotation of galaxies instead of the Dark Matter or [MOND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics) explanation?

This is IMO today, even more possible since there could be more [gravitoelectromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) contributions of a polarized quantum vacuum at a galactic scale than we initially assumed as suggested in this paper here by [Dragan Slavkov Hajdukovic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0847).

In the presence of the existing controversial experimental verification of the theoretical predicted values of the frame dragging mechanism for galactic size astronomical objects are there any other contributions that could intensify beyond its predicted values the frame dragging effect that are presently not accounted for?

Comment: We get this question every week; does this answer it for you? [Has frame dragging been accounted for in galactic rotation curves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/618981/has-frame-dragging-been-accounted-for-in-galactic-rotation-curves) Also see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/656419/is-it-true-that-frame-dragging-as-applied-to-galactic-rotation-curves-goes-as).

Comment: @knzhou My question however suggests the possibility that the predicted value of GR frame dragging not to be correct at the galactic scale and that might be other contributions to it that are not accounted for especially the added effect of the quantum vacuum polarization?

Comment: In that case, I think the answer is also no, because it would only work for galaxy rotation curves. DM also explains the motion of entire galaxies in galaxy clusters, and the spectrum of the CMB, the Bullet cluster, and many other things -- none of these look like the bulk rotation of a galaxy.

Comment: Also, I'd argue that you're basically proposing a form/source for the dark matter here, not elminating the need for dark matter.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Yes. DM could be not a discrete new particle but an unknown yet many-body effect of known particles.

Comment: It's not enough to just say that you don't like the predicted value of effect X in GR and would like it to be bigger. How specifically are you proposing to change GR so that frame dragging is increased above the value GR predicts for galaxies? Does this modification affect any other tests of GR? From experience, you will probably find that any concrete suggestion will run afoul of an experimental prediction, perhaps one you weren't expecting. If you can't answer these questions, you don't have a serious scientific proposal, just idle speculation, and there's not much more to say.

Comment: You can calculate quantum corrections within the effective field theory of gravity and they are always suppressed by the Planck scale and therefore unobservable in all plausible observations to date. Something very weird would have to be happening to have an observable effect of the quantum vacuum on gravitation (ignoring the cosmological constant).